# Split into partial fractions $\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, self-learning, partial-fractions

This is from "Calculus Made Easy", Exercises 10, Question 15 (page 147).  I've worked this one over and over and still haven't made progress.

This is my initial setup:

$$\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)^2} = \frac{A}{(x+2)} + \frac{Bx+C}{(x^2+x+1)} + \frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

then:

$$3x^2+2x+1 = A(x^2+x+1)^2 + (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$$

and I can solve for A by setting $x=-2$, which yields $A=1$.

I know the final answer is this:

$$\frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{x-1}{x^2+x+1} - \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

But I've worked this problem many ways and cannot make progress on the numerators for the other fractions.

Comment: There's an $x^4$ on the RHS that can only be cancelled by the $A,B$ coefficients.  What relationship between them accomplishes this?

Comment: Consider $3x^2+2x+1 \equiv A(x^2+x+1)^2 + (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$ and equate coefficients for $x^k$ in either side, you'll get system of $5$ linear equations. Or also try "setting $x$" to [the roots of $x^2+x+1=0$] $-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}2i$ )

Comment: @abiessu: I'm not seeing that.  I have a $x^4$ on the RHS and no $x^4$ term on the left, so $x^4=0$?

Comment: @Mike: no, the $A,B$ coefficients add to make $0x^4$ in the final result, but no specific value of $x$ is necessary...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)^2}= \frac {(3x^2+3x +3)-(x+2)}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)^2}=$$

$$ \frac {3}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)}-\frac { 1}{(x^2+x+1)^2} $$

Now you may proceed with the first fraction.

$$ \frac {3}{(x+2)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac {1}{x+2} -\frac {x-1}{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: I like this one.  I had not considered pulling $(x+2)$ out of the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand all the things from [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459213/split-into-partial-fractions-frac3x22x1x2x2x12#comment7110995_3459213).
[Method 1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2):
By [expanding](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+-%283*x%5E2%2B2*x%2B1%29+%2B+A*%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%5E2+%2B+%28B*x%2BC%29*%28x%2B2%29*%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29+%2B+%28D*x%2BE%29*%28x%2B2%29) [we get](https://tio.run/##PYzBjoMgFEXXw1e8HRBHk5ZZTGxIY61fITZpWkwxCgRdMEn/3UGGccF7h3sP2J/lZTT7tm5d1WSNW8BJNHNcgb99QQZH2IgFYpGO/1nYVTiX5LFIbKc/7xK9em/q1ESKRh3mdfevMW1S10AezK3Lw82HecBoui@Pl3TcyeJhJqtGSRwmInuLnBIB4knPYbVV3nSRPBG3LaRnTJHn6XnRK/28jyPBGeBspqdRauIp6o0DBUrDLBeiWlZ2sEeelujDOqVD84kBF4NRmuC0h7ZkHY32EG1QPQzbD5wrStf1Fw)
$$
\begin{cases}
A+B=0&&\hbox{ for }x^4\\\
2A+3B+C=0&&\hbox{ for }x^3\\\
3 A + 3 B + 3 C + D - 3=0&&\hbox{ for }x^2\\\
2 A + 2 B + 3 C + 2 D + E - 2=0&&\hbox{ for }x\\\
A + 2 C + 2 E - 1=0&&\hbox{ for }1
\end{cases}
$$
which boils down to [$A = 1, B = -1, C = 1, D = 0, E = -1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2B+A+%2B+2+C+%2B+2+E+-+1%3D0%2C+%2B+2+A+%2B+3+B+%2B+C%3D0%2C+%2B+A+%2B+B%3D0%2C+%2B+3+A+%2B+3+B+%2B+3+C+%2B+D+-+3%3D0%2C+%2B+2+A+%2B+2+B+%2B+3+C+%2B+2+D+%2B+E+-+2%3D0).
Method 2 "substitution":
with $x=-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ we get rid of $(x^2+x+1)$, can have equations for $D,E$ and after finding $D,E$ and bringing them to the LHS we can cancel by $(x+2)$ which boils down to [Mohammad Riazi-Kermani's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459247/233398)

Comment: This is good.  I always forget about creating a set of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know $A=1$ set $A$ equal to $1$. You get

$$3x^2+2x+1 = (x^2+x+1)^2 + (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$$
$$3x^2+2x+1 - (x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1) = (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$$
$$-x^4-2x^3 = (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$$
$$-x^3(x+2) = (Bx+C)(x+2)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)(x+2)$$
$$-x^3 = (Bx+C)(x^2+x+1) + (Dx+E)$$
$$-x^3 = Bx^3 + (B+C)x^2 + (B+C+D)x + (C+E)$$

and proceed from there

Comment: Maybe $x^3$ in the later equations on the LHS?